# How to write R program to solve the confidence interval?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

The problem: let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be random variable from $\mathrm{Poisson}(\theta)$. Under $H_0: \theta=\theta_0$, we want to find the $(1-\alpha)100\%$ confidence interval for $\theta$ by using the likelihood ratio interval, $-2\ln\lambda(x)$.  Now, I have $$1-\alpha = P\{2n[(\theta-\bar{X})-\bar{X} \ln(\theta/\bar{X})] \leq \chi^2_{0.05,df.=1}\}$$ where $2n[(\theta-\bar{X})-\bar{X}\ln(\theta/\bar{X})]$ has chi-square distribution with df. one for large sample size. This is not a formula for the upper limit of $\theta$. Thus I must use the R program to solve it but I have no idea. Please suggest me how to do and for improve my work. Thanks.

Comment: Normally confidence intervals are not found under a point null hypothesis.  Might it be that the problem was posed as testing the hypothesis by means of finding a confidence interval and seeing whether $\theta_0$ is in the interval?

Comment: Just solve for the two points where the likelihood equals your chi-square cutoff.

Comment: Thanks @Bey. So that point equal to the cutoff such that probability is $1-\alpha$ is the upper limit?

Comment: likelihood ratio cutoff = $\chi^2_{0.0\alpha,df.=1}$. your Poisson likelihood ratio functions should be unimodal, so there will be two points where this function equals the cutoff. These are your upper and lower endpoints to the CI.

Answer (score 1):

**Confidence Intervals for Poisson Mean**

Here are some clues that I hope are helpful. 
I am doing a grid search for the boundaries because I have no
idea what methods you have been taught for that.
Also, I do not know what kind of programming structure
you are supposed to use, so I will just show you the
steps I used to implement this method in one case.

This is more a 'proof of concept' than an answer, but it is
interesting to know whether the method works to produce apparently
useful CIs.

As you can see, I sampled $n = 100$ observations from
$Pois(\theta = 5)$ and then found a '95% confidence interval' (hoping
it would contain $\theta = 5,$ which happens to be the case).
It does seem that this method works.

This is an asymptotic criterion, and "infinity is a long way
off." If you want to verify that the CI truly has 95% coverage probability,
you would have to repeat the process several thousand times with
the same $\theta$ and sample size, and count the percentage of
iterations that produce an interval including 5. (But I do not
see that as part of the problem as stated.)

```
 n = 100;  x = rpois(n, 5);  xbar=mean(x)    # data
 th = seq(.1,10,by=.001);  q = qchisq(.95,1) # grid to search
 crit = 2*n*(th-xbar-xbar*log(th/xbar))      # criterion
 min(th[crit <= q])                          # lower end of CI
 ## 4.776
 max(th[crit <= q])                          # upper end of CI
 ## 5.67
```

From what you have revealed about your situation, this is
the best I can do. If you can't see how to modify what I have
shown into a suitable 'program', then please leave a comment
with additional information and maybe I (or someone else) can
be more helpful.

*Note:* As in the Comment from @Michael Hardy,
I do not see the relevance of the statement of $H_0,$ but
any $\theta_0$ in the interval would be "non-rejectable" as
as a null hypothesis against a two-sided alternative.

*Addenda:* (1) The following code (executed after the code above) will make a graph (not shown here) that
helps visualize what the grid search does. (See comment by @Bey.)

```
 cond = (th>4 & th<6)      # part of curve to plot
 plot(th[cond], crit[cond], type="l")
 abline(v=5.21)                       # sample mean
 abline(v=4.776, col="red")           # lower conf limit
 abline(v=5.670, col="red")           # upper conf limit
 abline(h=q, col="blue")              # chi-sq value
```

(2) A very similar interval estimate that is a lot
easier to handle comes from a Bayesian
context with an "improper" gamma prior, Poisson likelihood,
and, for the same data as above, posterior $Gamma(shape=521, rate=100).$ Such Bayesian interval estimates are sometimes
used as (frequentist) CIs. In this case, the computation is:

```
 qgamma(c(.025,.975), sum(x), n)
 ## 4.772175 5.666765
```

This computation might be used to judge the extent of values that
must be included in the grid vector 'th'.

Comment: Thank you so much, Trumbo for the ideas. Now,I am try to understand. As you said "repeat the process several thousand times ". Is it meaning of simulation?

Comment: If you only need to do one CI and trust that it comes close to really being "95%" then just running the code I have shown you will be OK. The 'grid' has to extend far enough to catch both ends of the CI. Usually from $.1\bar X$ to $10\bar X$ is plenty. If not, extend grid. You only have to repeat thousands of times if you want to check it really has 95% coverage; that does not seem to be required here. Please remember to click to Accept my answer (or another, if a better one appears soon). So your question will go off our list of unanswered ones. Leave a Comment in case of later questions.